# vi search and replace , puts a search result into other field in the same line

Tags: linux, vim, replace, text-editor, vi

Hi I have a file full of strings

> create_net_shape -no_snap -type path -net VDD -layer M9 -datatype **0** -path_type 0 -width 0.4 -route_type user_enter -points {{2965.64 302.835}  {2979.93 302.835}}

I would like to be able to search and replace in vi , a certain field based on a result of other filed

I nedd the output to be

> create_net_shape -no_snap -type path -net VDD -layer M9 -datatype **9** -path_type 0 -width 0.4 -route_type user_enter -points {{2965.64 302.835}  {2979.93 302.835}}

and so on

how can I use my search result in one field and apply it into the other

thanks

Comment: what you mean `a result of other filed`?

Comment: hi , what i mean that if I encounter at field #8 string "M9" I need my field #10 to be "9" ,
if I encounter  "...-layer M10 -datatype 0..." the output should be ...-layer M10 -datatype 10..."
I need to set a datatype number based on a layer number
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
:%s/\v-layer M([0-9]+) -datatype \zs[0-9]+/\1/
```

---

- The pattern will match `digits` right after `-datatype`.
- We substitute these `digits` with those right after `-layer M`
- Some advanced features. You can read the vimdoc with `:help \v` and `:help \zs`

Comment: Kev , thanks 
worked like a charm
can you please explain?
I assume () is similar to tcl , the search term go`s inside some var ,but how do you call it?
what is \v , \z
and \1

Comment: without `\v`(very magic), you need to rewrite `(...)` as `\(...\)` to capture a group

Comment: without `\zs`, you need to use `\@<=` (0-width preceding match). It's a syntax-sugar.